# Will all EOS platforms give me access to my frozen EOS tokens?

Tags: tokens

Will the snapshot that is made of my ethereum EOS address be made on all EOS platforms? Or will developers create there own funds?

Answer (score 2):

The chain which is selected by the majority will inevitably have to honor the snapshot, otherwise users will not:

- a) Choose the chain to vote on.
- b) have the tokens to support the vote-in for the chain to be raised.

Answer (score 1):

A chain can be made with modification of the software where tokens are not honored. However that chain will not be worth much because EOS uses proof of stake as a security mechanism which means that you want to have a lot of people who have put something on stake (i.e. bought the tokens).

Answer (score 1):

By 'other EOS platforms', I suppose you mean chains that may be forked from EOSIO on Github and launched by a team that is headed by a team other than Block.one.

If yes, then it is likely that other chains will honor the existing token holders while taking the snapshot of their mainnet. Although the token belonging to their chains may not be called EOS.

Examples of other chains that may be launched:
https://www.evolutionos.com/
https://medium.com/wax-io/worldwide-asset-exchange-development-update-wax-platform-base-technology-selection-and-more-7f280b90a371